# Setting language attribute for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design, accessibility

I am from Germany and using a screen reader making the Content of Stack Overflow accessible for me. Unfortunately no language attribute is set for Stack Overflow, so the screen reader reads all the English text Content with a German pronunciation, which is very exhausting.

With the background of accessible web and Guidelines like WCAG 2.1 ([Link to WCAG 2.1 - Chapter 3.1 Readable (filtered for language)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?currentsidebar=%23col_overview&tags=language#readable)) and ISO 9241 I would appreciate when Stack Overflow sets the language and reading direction attributes at the html-tag.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

This would be extremely helpful for users with disabilities.

Comment: Oh that's like my navigation trying to pronounce dutch street names with an English voice. It's hilarious, and I have no idea where it wants me to go some times. I can imagine this being a hassle if you rely on a screen reader though.

Comment: It would be not a problem for screen readers if the attribute is set correctly. It is also possible to set the lang-attribute only to parts of a page. And what shall People do if they have to rely on a screen Reader because they are blind?

Comment: This is a very thoughtful feature-request and I hope StackOverflow is able to implement this change soon. Unfortunately we cannot do much except wait for them to do it and upvote this request. All the best.

Comment: Should this be upped to Meta.SE ? There are a lot of sites that can be affected by this.

Comment: Do you use the screen reader on a PC? Or is this some other kind of device?

Comment: I use the screen reader JAWS on a PC.

Comment: To be clear: this has been waiting for over 3 years, the suggestion is well received, there is a clear citation of an accessibility guideline being violated... and just now we get an update to say this change has been "deferred"? When literally all that is being asked for is to set a couple of attributes in the `<html>` tag of the page source that gets emitted, something that any random intern ought to be able to figure out in an afternoon? Does this company actually care about accessibility? I am extremely unimpressed.

Comment: So, I checked, and apparently Stack Overflow pages *do* set a `lang` attribute (although not a `dir` attribute). So... it took more than three years to decide, that it's not even a priority, to **check what the site does already**?

Answer (score 9):

I hope they will implement this small change fast, as long as they don't you can install below userscript to tampermonkey. It will set the attribute for you. You can install it by clicking [here](https://github.com/saleweaver/userscript/raw/master/langatt.user.js), or copy from below code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         setLang
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://superuser.com/*
// @match        *://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        *://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match        *://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match        *://stackapps.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const el = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    el.setAttribute('lang', 'en');
    el.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
    // Your code here...
})();
```